# how to remove first and last characters from exploded php string

Tags: php

I have a string which I have exploded, it starts like this,

```
|Crime|Drama|Mystery|Suspense|Thriller|
```

I would like to remove the first | and the last |
after exploding so that the exploded text can look like this

```
Crime,Drama,Mystery,Suspense,Thriller
```

is this possible to do?

here is my code so far.

```
<?php $explodegen = explode("|", $val->Genre); ?>
<?php
foreach($explodegen as $exploding){
echo "".$exploding.",";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
substr($string, 1, -1);
```

Then explode it.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options then:

- [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) the input to strip the `|` before exploding.
- Or [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) on the result array to have the empty results removed.
- If it's just for output use [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) to to transform `|` into `,` (and apply [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) beforehand).

I'd personally rather extract the strings using [`preg_match_all("/[^|]+/")`](http://php.net/preg_match_all).

Comment: I gotta disagree with `preg_match_all` for this use case. It's quite cumbersome: First you have to pass it a reference object to put the result in, then you have to dig into that object's internals to actually get the desired data out.

Comment: Actually all of the the splitting+rejoining variations are pointless, since it's just for converting the delimiter prior outputting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = '|Crime|Drama|Mystery|Suspense|Thriller|';
$delim = '|';
$exploded = explode($delim, trim($input, $delim));
echo implode(',', $exploded);
```

You should get

```
Crime,Drama,Mystery,Suspense,Thriller
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag: `preg_split('/\|/', $in, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`
2. [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php): `array_filter(explode('|', $in));`
3. [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php): `explode('|', trim($in, '|'));`

Option 1 is the only one that you can do in a single function call. Option 3, however, is the only one that *keeps* empty elements if they are in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this. Here's one option:

```
$str = "|Crime|Drama|Mystery|Suspense|Thriller|";

echo $str = str_replace("|", ",", trim($str, "|"));
```

Result:

```
Crime,Drama,Mystery,Suspense,Thriller
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/dZ2s9LUj)

Answer (score 0):

`trim($string, "|")` would remove comma from the beginning and end of a string.

and

`rtrim($string, "|")` would remove comma from the end of a string.